# Obtener fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy tratando de obtener la fecha actual con el siguiente comando

```
time_t fecha=time(NULL);
asctime(localtime(&fecha))
```

Y me la muestra así:  `Mon Oct 24 20:36:55 2022`

¿Hay alguna otra manera de obtener la fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy? Por ejemplo: 24/10/2022 20:36:55.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según explica el autor de esta [**respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811/3673291#3673291), tendrías que utilizar la función [**`strftime()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) para poder modificar el formato que te trae el **`localtime`**, tu código sería el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    time_t fecha = time(NULL);
    char buffer[26];
    struct tm* tm_info;

    tm_info = localtime(&fecha);

    strftime(buffer, 26, "%d/%m/%Y", tm_info);
    puts(buffer);
 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
// 26/10/2022
```

Comment: Muy claro, muchas gracias!